# RunCode macro action from 'hybrid' Access web database error

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access web database

- In this database, I have a web form with a button on it
- In its on-click event macro, it calls `RunMacro Macro1` (client-macro) which fires successfully
- in Macro1, if I call `RunCode Function Name: DoTest()` it returns the error: "The function you entered can't be used in this expression... Error Number 2426 (or 2950 if I have an "=" symbol in front of my function)

This issue is easily reproduced by doing these steps:

1. Create a blank **web** database in MS Access
2. Add and save a table
3. Create a default form from that table and put a button on it
4. Create a new VBA module "Module1" and put the following function in it:

   ```
   Public Function DoTest()
       MsgBox "Test function runs smoothly"
   End Function
   ```
5. Create a client-macro "Macro1" with `RunCode: Function Name: DoTest()` (Note that IntelliSense recognizes the macro, and it runs fine from here)
6. Create the form's button's on-click macro event `RunMacro: Macro Name: Macro1`
7. Click the form's button from form-view to receive the error:

> **The function you entered can't be used in this expression.**
>
> - You may have used a DoEvents, LBound, UBound, Spc, or Tab function in an
>     expression.
> - You may have used an aggregate function, such as Count, in a design grid or in a calculated control or field.

Clicking "Ok" shows error number 2426 or 2950 depending on if you have an equals sign before your function name or not in the client-side macro's RunCode command.

I've tried all of the tips from this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244980/ms-access-runcode-macro-cannot-find-my-procedure) without any luck. Access seems to find the function fine, as replacing the function name with gibberish gives a very different error.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

In my actual web database which uses Access Services published to SharePoint 2010, I use an `If IsClient() Then` macro statement on the form's button's on-click event to ensure that the VBA is only running in the client mode, but that is not relevant to the error I'm receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extra digging, I came across [this post in another forum](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t1968469.html).
Here, the author simply explains that what I'm trying to do doesn't work (when you would think that it should).

Because it's on another forum, I'll spell out the workaround that also worked for me (credit: jakedrew, UtterAccess post, Jun 9 2011).  Basically, you need to use a client-form in addition to a client-macro as intermediate steps to get from your web form to VBA.  I made this effective for my current application by doing the following:

1. I re-saved my function as a sub instead:

   ```
   Public Sub DoTest(ByVal intArg As Integer)
       MsgBox "Test sub runs smoothly with argument = " & intArg
   End Sub
   ```
2. Create a client-form (mine is named "frmVBA_Bridge") and create the following `OnOpen` event:

   ```
   Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
       ' run your code using this command.  Note that if you don't have an argument, you won't include the part of this line following the comma
       Application.Run TempVars("SubName").Value, TempVars("Arg1").Value
       ' reset the "parameters"
       TempVars("SubName").Value = ""
       TempVars("Arg1").Value = 0
       DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveYes
   End Sub
   ```
3. The client-side macro "Macro1" now instead does:

   ```
   OpenForm
     Form Name  frmVBA_Bridge
     View Form
     Where Condition
     Data Mode
     Window Mode  Hidden
   ```
4. The web form's button's on-click embedded macro gets changed to:

   ```
   If  IsClient() = True Then
     SetTempVar
       Name SubName
       Expression ="DoTest"
     SetTempVar
       Name Arg1
       Expression = 100
     RunMacro
       Macro Name Macro1
   End If
   ```

Quite a bit of a workaround for such a simple thing, but it seems to do the job!