# MS Access - can't run subs in module from RunMacro

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have several modules in my Access 2013 database, which include public subs and functions. However they don't show up in the Run Macro list, and I can't call them if I build a macro with a RunMacro or RunCode command. I have security settings to allow for all macros.

Is there any additional step other than declaring your functions/subs as public in order to run them outside of the VBA window?

Comment: Are you including the '()' at the end of the name? If not, try adding...

Comment: Yes I've tried with and without parentheses, and tried adding the Module name in front of it.

Comment: Have you tried the run macro command? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177365(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Just so I'm clear on this...  is the issue (a) you can't get a function/sub to run, or (b) you can't see a list of functions/sub's when you build a macro? I agree with the two posters below that you need to use the 'RunCode' action. If I build a macro, use RunCode as the action and manually type in 'GetNetworkUserName()', it will execute that function. If the issue is you are not certain if it runs or not, then add a message box or debug.print to the function then run the macro.

Comment: The issue is (a)- it doesn't run, though it isn't offered as a choice either. I commented below that it doesn't run in RunMacro or RunCode, so I'll update the question to show that.

Comment: It must be a Function that you specify with RunCode. Doesn't matter if Public or not, but it can't be a Sub. I created  Function 'SendMsgToMe' which contained only a MsgBox, created and saved a Macro that used RunCode and the executed it. Worked fine. If you are unable to do a similar simple test, then create a blank database and repeat the test. If it works, maybe your DB is in need of repair or rebuilding.

Answer (score 2):

For running public VBA sub/function in macro you should use `RunCode`action, not `RunMacro`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [run code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177365(v=office.12).aspx) macro?

Comment: RunCode and RunMacro both give me the same error. It can't find any of the public subs in my modules.

Comment: @kainC have you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244980/ms-access-runcode-macro-cannot-find-my-procedure

Comment: thanks majjam, this turned out to be what I needed. It had to be specified with the RunCode - AND could only call a function, not a sub. Counterintuitive, since RunCode doesn't handle the return value anyway